# Use of dynamic memory allocation for a client socket class in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, memory-management

Coming from a Java background I am still grappling with C++ memory allocation and when to use smart pointer, automatic stack allocation or dynamic stack allocation.

However I have a concrete use case:

I created a class which consists only of a client socket and a function which sends a std::string to the target machine and closes the connection at the end.

I use this client class in several functions. The functions where I use the client class are triggered by certain events. Therefore every event notification is sent via socket.

My question is, should I use automatic stack allocation here? My guess is yes, as I don't need dynamic allocation. If this is true, under what circumstances would a client class be in the position to be allocated dynamically or when would it be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that a socket/file descriptor is really just an `int` [handle](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Handle_Body) on an object managed by the OS, I'd go for stack allocation + copy construction or pass-by-reference whenever possible. You're only copying an `int` and the relative overhead of indirection through a pointer would be great.

(If you're also storing the hostname and some other stuff, consider using a shared pointer.)

Comment: I use the boost socket library, does this make any difference?

Comment: @platzhirsch: I'm not familiar with that, but if you can get by with just pass-by-reference, don't allocate on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

I'd allocate on the stack only if the lifetime of the allocated object is tightly bound to the procedural scope.

If you ever need to pass references around that might (need to) be kept after the function returns, you need to dynamically allocate it.

Of course in C++ the point quickly becomes moot for the actual storage volumes, since e.g. STL containers (vector, list, map et friends) do their element allocations dynamically anyway [1]

So it really is about lifetimes.

I find myself managing lifetimes by class-responsability rather than function scope[1]. I regularly end up with a single Application (class) instance containing all 'global' objects, each containing their objects etc. The application object can be a static global, or just a stack alloc-ed local variable in main - it doesn't matter much as long as you don't declare a `const char [300][400]` member in it :)

$0.02

[1] that is: in the absense of a particularly mischievous custom allocator which you are probably not interested in at the moment :)
[2] With closures, function scope can get eerily close to class responsability - in the same way that functional languages use closures to mimic OOP patternss